# How can one force TagHelpers and HtmlHelpers to use explicit Controller and ActionMethod values in ASP.NET 5 BETA 8

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

It seems that some sort of controller validation has been built into the TagHelpers and HTMLHelpers in ASP.NET 5.
However instead of giving a compile error or warnings when building the project, it instead renders  the controller and method names as empty strings.

To simulate:

I create a controller in my project called MyCustomController

I have the default Home Controller but I don't have a Dog ActionMethod in any of my controllers

```
<a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="Dog" asp-route-id="1">Dog</a>
```

renders to

```
<a href="">Dog</a>
```

I would prefer the URL renders explicitly to /Home/Dog/

Another example: (I intentionally add a route id to Create)

```
<a asp-controller="MyCustom" asp-action="Create" asp-route-id="1">Month Create</a>
<a asp-controller="MyCustom" asp-action="Edit" asp-route-id="1">Month Edit</a>
<a asp-controller="MyCustom" asp-action="Delete" asp-route-id="1">Month Delete</a>
```

MyCustomController methods:

```
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Create()

[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> Edit(int id)

[HttpGet("{id:int}")]
public async Task<IActionResult> Delete(int id)
```

Renders to:

```
<a href="/MyCustom/Create/1">Create</a>
<a href="/1">Edit</a>
<a href="/1">Delete</a>
```

I can't see a reason why the TagHelpers are not rendering the Controller and Action Method name for Edit and Delete in the urls.

I also tested HTML ActionLink Helpers and the output is the same as the TagHelpers

```
@Html.ActionLink("Create", "Create", new { id = item.Id })
@Html.ActionLink("Edit", "Edit", new { id = item.Id })
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.Id })
```

Render to:

```
<a href="/MyCustom/Create/1">Create</a> 
<a href="/1">Edit</a> 
<a href="/1">Delete</a>
```

It then took me considerable time to debug as there was no indication what the problem was.
I fixed it by:

- Removing the [HttpGet] attributes for the Edit, Delete action methods.
- Changing [HttpPost("{id:int}")] to [HttpPost] for the Post Edit action method.

My Question:
Is there a way to set  TagHelpers and HtmlHelpers to render explicitly without validating against the controller?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted [this question](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/issues/3432) as a ASP.NET MV GitHub repos issues

This is the response I received from [Ryan Nowak](https://github.com/rynowak)

This is a change to routing behavior. You can revert to the old behavior like this:

```
using Microsoft.AspNet.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNet.Routing;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

namespace BestEffortLinkGenerationWebSite
{
    public class Startup
    {
        // Set up application services
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.AddMvc();

            services.Configure<RouteOptions>((options) =>
            {
                options.UseBestEffortLinkGeneration = true;
            });
        }

        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
        {
            app.UseCultureReplacer();

            app.UseMvcWithDefaultRoute();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create an issue about this in the [mvc repro](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc).

If you don't like the default behaviour you can change the default or replace the default with your own taghelpers. for example see [Taghelpers](https://github.com/Anderman/TagHelpers)